# Add web.config variation -> Compilation error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config

After I added a Solution Configuration, added a web.config variation to my MVC project, and compile the project, i received a compilation error for each dll file. IE:

Error   102 Metadata file 'C:\Framework\Dev\Source\Framework\Framework.Common\bin\bellcadev005\Framework.Common.dll' could not be found Framework.Targeting

bellcadev005 is the name of the Solution Configuration

I don't understand why additional metadata files are needed when adding a variation of a web.config file.